# Generate an image and save it on my server and give url

Tags: asp.net, image, post

Hi i have following requirement.

1)

A website will send a get request with a message  and callback url as a query.

i want to generate an image and save it on my server and give a url to the calling server on the callback url as a query paramater.

I already have the code to generate the image.

I want to know how to save it on my server to be available to the calling server.

and he should have no access to other images in the folder.

2)

Can any one also tell me how to send an image to a url in a POST request.

Please help...
Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save the image

```
outputImage.Save(TheFileNameTosaveIt, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

where outputImage is the Bitmap created image.

one way to send the image on the url is to make a Responce.Redirect

Comment: But what if my server is in a hosted environment and i dont know the actual path of the Virtual Directory.. Then is it still possible????

Comment: And what about the POST request to send the image.

Comment: @Shekhar the path is HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath . So in this you add your image file name. Now after the Post you make your process, and at the end you make Responce.Redirect